# Is Android pop up notification only available on lollipop? How can I get the same effect for pre lollipop device?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I set the priority and the heads up notification works fine on lollipop devices. However, is it possible to get the same effect on non lollipop deivecs? Or do I have to do a toast or something? Thanks!